# Jsoup.select not selecting CSS path but chrome selects it

Tags: html, css-selectors, jsoup, html-parsing

i'm trying to select some paragraph in www.zoho.com using following css paths:

> 1. html > body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(3) > section > div > div > div > div
> 2. div.zh-banner-wrap > div.content-wrap.animated:first-child

it is working fine in Chrome inspect element css path search

But while i'm trying this in jsoup it is not working.

Java code :

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.zoho.com").get();

        Element el = doc.selectFirst("html > body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(3) > section > div > div > div > div");
        if(el != null) {
            System.out.println(el.text());
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the code also ?

Comment: i've modified the question and added code. @manfromnowhere

Comment: @manfromnowhere i tried with try.jsoup.org also. It is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what are expected output in your case. 
When I am using your selector in chrome console

```
document.querySelector("html > body > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(3) > section > div > div > div")
```

I got null. Same as in Jsoup.

This is because

```
document.querySelector("html > body > div:nth-of-type(2)")
```

is

```
<div class=​"ztopstrip-container">​</div>​
```

If in your case output is different, check if there is a content loaded dynamically via JavaScript.

Compare result of `System.out.println(doc.html())` with source code from web browser.

Comment: Yes. I was about to close question. The content was generated dynamically via JS. So the diff arises. Any way thanks @Luk For the right answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.zoho.com").get();
Element el = doc.selectFirst("div:nth-of-type(3) > section > div > div > div > div");
if(el != null) {
     System.out.println(el.text());
}
```

more information you can find [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: it will work for this case alone. Not for all. i need why it is not working in jsoup for all the cases.